# Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object after SPQuery

Tags: application-pages, spweb, spquery, dispose, spsite

this code run yesterday very well and today I've been trying to solve this error for hour now :

> Please close SPWeb objects when you are done with all objects obtained from them, but not before

I tried to close each opened web by it still doesn't work !!
here's my code I hope someone can help me !

```
protected void loadItemsFromCorrList(string contentTypeName)
{
    using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url))
    {
        // set a data table to fill GridView control with Types Items

        SPListItemCollection collListItems = getAllCorrListItemsforCT(contentTypeName);
        DataTable GVdataSource = new DataTable();
        GVdataSource.Columns.Add(Fields.CorrListFldTypesIN, typeof(string));
        GVdataSource.Columns.Add(Fields.CorrListFldValeurIN);
        GVdataSource.Columns.Add(Fields.CorrListFldOrdreIN);

        foreach (SPListItem myListItem in collListItems)
        {
            DataRow myTypeValueOrderRow = GVdataSource.NewRow();
            myTypeValueOrderRow[Fields.CorrListFldTypesIN] = myListItem[Fields.CorrListFldTypesIN].ToString();
            myTypeValueOrderRow[Fields.CorrListFldValeurIN] = myListItem[Fields.CorrListFldValeurIN];
            myTypeValueOrderRow[Fields.CorrListFldOrdreIN] = myListItem[Fields.CorrListFldOrdreIN];
            GVdataSource.Rows.Add(myTypeValueOrderRow);
        }
        TypeValueOrderGV.DataSource = GVdataSource;
        TypeValueOrderGV.DataBind();
    }
}

protected SPListItemCollection getAllCorrListItemsforCT(string myCTName)
{
   SPList corrList = getSelectedList(Fields.CorrListName);
  using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url))
  {
    SPListItemCollection rLIC = null;
    using (SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb())
    {
        if (corrList != null)
        {
            SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
            myQuery.Query = "<Where><AND><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + Fields.CorrListFldTitreIN + "'/>"
                + "<Value Type='Text'>" + myCTName + "</Value></Eq>"
                + "<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + Fields.CorrListFldFonctionIN + "'/>"
                + "<Value Type='Text'>" + Fields.GenerateChronoFnTitre + "</Value></Eq></AND></Where>";


            SPListItemCollection allCorrListItems = corrList.GetItems(myQuery);
            Label_Hello.Text += "Hi | " + allCorrListItems[1].Fields[1].ToString();
            rLIC = allCorrListItems;
        }
    }
    return rLIC;
    }
}

getSelectedList(string ListTitle)
{
    using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url))
    {
        SPWebCollection myWebs = mySite.AllWebs;
        SPList rList=null;
        foreach (SPWeb myWeb in myWebs)
        {
            using (myWeb)
            {
                SPListCollection myLists = myWeb.Lists;
                foreach (SPList myList in myLists)
                {
                    if (myList.Title.Equals(ListTitle))
                        rList = myList;
                }
            }
            myWeb.Dispose();
        }
        return rList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Hugh said, in the getSelectedList function you have the first error.

```
using (myWeb)
{
    SPListCollection myLists = myWeb.Lists;
    foreach (SPList myList in myLists)
    {
        if (myList.Title.Equals(ListTitle))
            rList = myList;
    }
}
myWeb.Dispose();
```

This will dispose the myWeb istance after the using block. The suggested way from the dispose pattern is instead:

```
foreach (SPWeb innerWeb in siteCollection.AllWebs)
{
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        if(innerWeb != null)
           innerWeb.Dispose();
    }
}
```

That said, that's not the only problem. You are experiencing an error on "SPListItemCollection allCorrListItems = corrList.GetItems(myQuery);". If you think about it this is expected. You are using the list istance returned by the getSelectedList method, but by now the parent SPWeb istance has already been disposed. You would need to rewrite the code and dispose the web only when you are done working with the list.

Furthermore, the getAllCorrListItemsforCT method seems to open some new SPSite and SPWeb instance that aren't used. Also, the istance are based on the site url, so probably you could just use the SPContext istances (which are automatically disposed for you).

---

**EDIT:**
About the solutions. IMHO, when you return an SPList istance to a caller method, you are actually delegating the caller to perform appropiate disposing. That said, I would rework the methods to have it so that you pass the web istance to the list finder method - that way you can dispose the istance in the caller method.

Comment: so what should i do ? write it all in the same place ? but what if I needed this fonction again am I gonna write again!!

Comment: Sorry, wrong comment (two windows open at the same time). Give me some time to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

When you create something in a using statement, it gets disposed afterwards.

```
using(myWeb) {...}
myWeb.Dispose();
```

You should take off the using statement, and also check to see if the myWeb is disposable.

```
using (SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb())
```

This instance of use is correct and will auto dispose myWeb.

Comment: it still doesn't work and when I followed the error it's on SPListItemCollection allCorrListItems = corrList.GetItems(myQuery); what does that mean !!

Comment: You aren't even using mysite and myweb in the second code sample. Also you can just open a list up by it's name: SPList myList = SPWeb.Lists["listname"] without having to iterate through them all.

Comment: @HughWood I would suggest SPWeb.Lists.TryGetList("listname") to avoid handling errors if the list doesn't exist

Comment: Yes I should of wrote that but I was using the key which is faster in a project that I know it exists, and automatically wrote that, I wasn't thinking, then you check if(list == null) { code here for the list has been found }

Answer (score 1):

Install and run [SPDisposeChecker](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck) on your compiled dll or exe. It should suggest line items in your code to analyse.

Also, please review Microsoft's excellent article on [Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Services Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the pattern you've developed to
**`getSelectedList(string ListTitle)`** and
 
**`protected SPListItemCollection getAllCorrListItemsforCT(string myCTName)`**
isn't that you forgot to dispose an `SPWeb` object (of course you should fix the `myWeb.Dispose()` issue as suggested above).

The problem is that you return **`SPList`** and **`SPListItemCollection`** from your methods ***after you've disposed the `SPWeb` where those objects lie***. When you reference to those returned objects somewhere else in your code, SP detects that the web is already disposed and opens it again. If you read carefully the error message "Detected use of `SPRequest` for previously closed `SPWeb` object", it suggests that you are referencing to an `SPWeb` object which has been closed. With this information, you should consider other approach: either not disposing the `SPWebs` in your methods but only after you're finished handling or making references to the returned `SPList` and `SPListItemCollection` or just doing the `SPListItemCollection` and `SPList` handling within one using(`myWeb`) statement.